# How to replace uuid column with a word in vim

Tags: regex, vim

The text I got as the following lines (it is a sql script)

```
('63d3a510-321c-11e1-9fe7-000c2956598e', 1, 13, 'aaa', 'aa', 1309, 0),
('63d3a5ba-321c-11e1-9fe7-000c2956598e', 3, 34, 'bbb', 'bb', 3402, 1),
('63d3a6aa-321c-11e1-9fe7-000c2956598e', 3, 34, 'ccc', 'cc', 3403, 1),
```

I need to replace the all uuids with uuid().

How can i do it in vim?

Answer (score 4):

If all your lines are of the same shape, this will do:

```
:%s,'[^']\+',uuid(),
```

in command mode.

(yes, I use `,` instead of the more classical `/` as a separator, but it works just as well -- and is easier to type on an azerty keyboard layout :))

Comment: Great tip about using , instead of / !

Answer (score 4):

It's safer to match `uuid` precisely:

```
:%s/'[-[:xdigit:]]\{36}'/uuid()/g
```

Answer (score 1):

If they were few lines I would use the `.` to repeat last change.

```
lca'uuid()<ESC>j.j.
```

Explanation:

```
l          # One position right to set cursor inside '...'
ca'        # Change content between '...'
uuid()     # Write literal string.
<ESC>      # Press <ESC> key to exit insert mode and return to normal mode.
j.         # Move one line down and repeat last change.
j.         # Move to last line and repeat last change.
```

Answer (score 1):

[easy way] In this particular case (columns are aligned) I would use visual block mode:

1. <C-v>(select area between '')x
2. <C-v>(select the column with second
       quote mark ')Iuuid()<ESC>

where "<C-v>(select)I" allows to insert the same text in each selected row.

Comment: Instead of deleting and inserting text you can just press `c` to change the selection.